# iterating over and removing from a map

Tags: java

I was doing:

```
for (Object key : map.keySet())
    if (something)
        map.remove(key);
```

which threw a ConcurrentModificationException, so i changed it to:

```
for (Object key : new ArrayList<Object>(map.keySet()))
    if (something)
        map.remove(key);
```

this, and any other procedures that modify the map are in synchronized blocks.

**is there a better solution?**

Comment: If this method and the other method that modify the map are in synchronized blocks, I don't see why you have to do anything? Maybe I'm not understanding your question completely? Can ou please post the rest of the code?

Comment: @Raedwald, this question and it's accepted answer are more succinct than the other IMO.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

As of Java 8 you could do this as follows:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> <boolean expression>);
```

Oracle Docs: [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa

Comment: Note that `map.values()` and `map.keySet()` also support `removeIf()`.

Comment: What is the behaviour of removeIf on map.values()? it removes all the key->val elements pointing to such value?

Comment: In removeIf() we are giving condition, it will remove all the matched records

Answer (score 411):

Here is a code sample to use the iterator in a for loop to remove the entry.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    put("test", "test123");
    put("test2", "test456");
  }
};

for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
    if(entry.getKey().equals("test")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you do: `it.remove()` and never `collection.remove(key)` inside a loop. It's great!

Comment: This answer is good for code before Java 8, but elron's answer is preferable if you are using Java 8. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29187813/2077574

Comment: This works great in Android too.

Comment: If an item were added to this Map while it was being recursed to remove items wouldn't it still throw a ConcurrentModificationException?

Comment: Hashmap has a fail-fast iterator. Then why does it.remove() not throw a ConcurrentModificationException ?

Comment: Since Java 8, you can also use this instead: `map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().equals("test"));`

Comment: @KPD This is still better if we have some other logic as well inside the for loop, which was my case.

Answer (score 110):

Use a real iterator.

```
Iterator<Object> it = map.keySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext())
{
  it.next();
  if (something)
    it.remove();
 }
```

Actually, you might need to iterate over the `entrySet()` instead of the `keySet()` to make that work.

Comment: This does seem a bit more elegant than my solution of iterating over the entry set. Its not very obvious though that removing from the key set removes things from the map (i.e. the key set can be a copy)

Comment: Sorry to double comment. I have confirmed that removing from the key set indeed removes from the map, although not as obvious as removing from the entry set.

Comment: Iterating over the key set is the way to do it.

Comment: (Although to match the question, it should be `Iterator<Integer>`.)

Comment: Tom, in the first loop he's using "for (Object key:", so that's why I used an Object iterator.

Comment: `Iterator.next()` or in this case `it.next()` must be invoked before the call to `remove` otherwise there will be an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @broiyan, you are correct, I forgot that.

Comment: For the record, this also works for the map values: `Iterator it = map.values().iterator()`, then `it.remove()` will remove it entry.

Comment: Hashmap has a fail-fast iterator. Then why does it.remove() not throw a ConcurrentModificationException ?

Comment: @sumanth232 A fail-fast iterator fails when _something else_ modifies the container concurrently.  You are allowed to use the iterator as intended.  In this answer, nothing is modifying the key Set except for the iterator, and that is translated through to the Map owning that Set as well.  Only one operation per container is occurring at a time; no concurrency.

Answer (score 50):

> **is there a better solution?**

Well, there is, definitely, a **better** way to do so in a **single statement**, but that depends on the condition based on which elements are removed.

For eg: remove all those elements where `value` is *test*, then use below:

```
map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton("test"));
```

**UPDATE**
It can be done in a single line using Lambda expression in Java 8.

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e-> <boolean expression> );
```

I know this question is way too old, *but there isn't any harm in updating the better way to do the things :)*

Comment: It may be an old question but that really helped me. I'd never heard of Collections.singleton() and I had no idea you could remove elements from a map by calling removeAll() on values()! Thank you.

Comment: To remove the element which key is test:
map.keySet().removeAll(Collections.singleton("test"));

Comment: @MarouaneLakhal To remove the element which key is test, wouldn't you just do map.remove("test"); ?

Comment: @dzeikei as stated in the question, map.remove(key) threw a ConcurrentModificationException when he was looping over the map.keySet().

Comment: @MarouaneLakhal If you already know the key of an element of the map you want to remove already, why are you looping in the first place? There can only be one entry in the map with the same key.

Answer (score 25):

**ConcurrentHashMap**

You can use [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

It implements `ConcurrentMap` (which extends the `Map` interface).

**E.g.**:

```
Map<Object, Content> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Content>();

for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
    if (something) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

This approach leaves your code untouched. Only the `map` type differs.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that a ConcurrentHashMap does not allow "null" as value (or key), so if by any chance you are dealing with a map containing a null, you could not use this approach.

Answer (score 9):

Java 8 support a more declarative approach to iteration, in that we specify the result we want rather than how to compute it. Benefits of the new approach are that it can be more readable, less error prone.

```
public static void mapRemove() {

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
        {
            put(1, "one");
            put(2, "two");
            put(3, "three");
        }
    };

    map.forEach( (key, value) -> { 
        System.out.println( "Key: " + key + "\t" + " Value: " + value );  
    }); 

    map.keySet().removeIf(e->(e>2)); // <-- remove here

    System.out.println("After removing element");

    map.forEach( (key, value) -> { 
        System.out.println( "Key: " + key + "\t" + " Value: " + value ); 
    });
}
```

And result is as follows:

```
Key: 1   Value: one
Key: 2   Value: two
Key: 3   Value: three
After removing element
Key: 1   Value: one
Key: 2   Value: two
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `Iterator` to safely remove element while traversing a map.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Paul Tomblin. I usually use the keyset's iterator, and then base my condition off the value for that key:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Integer key = it.next();
    Object val = map.get(key);
    if (val.shouldBeRemoved()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the entrySet instead of using the keySet and doing a get every time. FindBugs even has a detector for this: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#WMI_WRONG_MAP_ITERATOR

Answer (score 2):

An alternative, more verbose way

```
List<SomeObject> toRemove = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();
for (SomeObject key: map.keySet()) {
    if (something) {
        toRemove.add(key);
    }
}

for (SomeObject key: toRemove) {
    map.remove(key);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And this should work as well..

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> running = ... create and populate map

Set<Entry<Integer, String>> set = running.entrySet();    

for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : set)
{ 
  if (entry.getKey()>600000)
  {
    set.remove(entry.getKey());    
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `running.remove(entry.getKey());`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can iterate over the map looking for the keys to remove and storing them in a separate collection. Then remove the collection of keys from the map. Modifying the map while iterating is usually frowned upon. This idea may be suspect if the map is very large.

Comment: If you can use a for-each it's definitely the more elegant solution

Answer (score -2):

```
Set s=map.entrySet();
Iterator iter = s.iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry =(Map.Entry)iter.next();

    if("value you need to remove".equals(entry.getKey())) {
         map.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be some explanation as well.

Comment: i think map.remove will thow concurrentModificationExceptiom