# Can i remove an element while enumerating through a Properties object?

Tags: java

Can i remove an element while enumerating through a Properties
object ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried?</strike> (sorry, didn't pay attention, you've set the *beginner* flag ;))

Properties is a subclass of HashMap and HashMap offers an iterator, which is in Fact a subclass of [AbstractMapIterator](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap$AbstractMapIterator.html). This iterator implements the remove method. So the answer is - yes, if you *iterate* through the Properties object.

Comment: Have you tried would have been the right answer :) Just the fact that Properties extends Map does not mean all methods of Map are available on Properties. cf UnsupportedOperationException. In Java it seems to be acceptable to extend but not obey the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @Hemal, yes, I know. With a good IDE and some experience you can code such a test in less time that it takes to put a question on SO. But he's a beginner and so I 'deleted' this line in my answer.

Comment: @Andreas_D I didnt get how Properties is a subclass of HashMap. According to java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html it is a subclass of HashTable. Can you explain?

Answer (score 5):

[`Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)`implements`[`Map<Object,Object>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), so you can iterate over the [`Set.iterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#iterator%28%29) of its [`Map.entrySet()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), and call [`Iterator.remove()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) on certain entries.

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("k1", "foo");
    prop.put("k2", "bar");
    prop.put("k3", "foo");
    prop.put("k4", "bar");

    System.out.println(prop); // prints "{k4=bar, k3=foo, k2=bar, k1=foo}"

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Object,Object>> iter = prop.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Object,Object> entry = iter.next();
        if (entry.getValue().equals("bar")) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prop); // prints "{k3=foo, k1=foo}"
```

The reason why you want to call `remove()` on an `iterator()` is because you don't want to cause a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

#### Related questions

- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)
- [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

---

Many beginners often question the value of `interface` in Java: this is a great example to show just how powerful `interface` can be. `Properties implements Map<Object,Object>`, so unless documented otherwise, all the things you can do with a `Map`, you can do with a `Properties`. The information in the above question is directly relevant and directly applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, We can remove an element while enumerating the properties elements

```
Enumeration<String> enu = (Enumeration<String>)p.propertyNames();
        while(enu.hasMoreElements()){
            String key = enu.nextElement();
            String props = p.getProperty(key);
            
            System.out.println(key + "-" + props );
            if(key.equals("neice")) p.remove(key);
        }
```