# How to remove a key from HashMap while iterating over it?

Tags: java, dictionary

I am having `HashMap` called `testMap` which contains `String, String`.

```
HashMap<String, String> testMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

When iterating the map, if `value` is match with specified string, I need to remove the key from map.

i.e.

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : testMap.entrySet()) {
  if(entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Sample")) {
    testMap.remove(entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

`testMap` contains `"Sample"` but I am unable to remove the key from `HashMap`. 
Instead getting error :

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)"
```

Comment: Please always copy/paste code snippets, rather than type 'something like' the code used.  The original code shown could not throw a run-time exception, since it was uncompilable.

Comment: Another option, while cludgy, is to create a list of the objects you want to remove while you're iterating. Then you can create another loop after your initial loop that iterates over that list and removes them from the hashmap.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Try:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iter = testMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> entry = iter.next();
    if("Sample".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue())){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

With Java 1.8 and onwards you can do the above in just one line:

```
testMap.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> "Sample".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getValue()));
```

Comment: What if you want to remove an item that isn't the one that your iterator is on?

Comment: @HDave It's possible using a method like `Map.remove (Object key)`, but should not be done during iteration. If you use any remove method other than `Iterator.remove()` during iteration, the results of the iteration are undefined. Either wait until the iterator is "on" the entry you want to remove and use `Iterator.remove()`, or do it outside of (before/after) the iteration loop. If it's the latter, make sure to get a new iterator from the entry set before doing any iteration on the map, as any previous iterator will yield undefined results.

Comment: Or you could use a `for` loop with similar semantics, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1884916/32453

Comment: I had this problem many years ago before Java 8 and I used ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap.

Answer (score 15):

Use [Iterator.remove().](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29)