# How to remove a key from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

i have this hashmap

```
HashMap <Integer,Integer> H = new HashMap <Integer,Integer>();
```

and when i try to remove the key from HashMap i recive this error

```
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:922)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956)
at Livre.montantTotal(Livre.java:42)**
```

this is my code

```
for (int e : H.keySet()){
    H.put(e, H.get(e)-1);
    if (H.get(e) == 0){
        H.remove(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify a collection while you're iterating through it.

Comment: well, you can use the remove() method on an Iterator (so expand for loop into a proper Iterator), but you wont be able to add to the collection while you are iterating it.  perhaps collect up the additions in a list and add them at the end.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto Mmm, it is related but not really duplicate because here it's a map

Comment: why is everyone voting this down? it might be a duplicate but its a common issue

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error because you are trying to remove the element and rearrange the hashmap while its already in use (while looping through it).

To loop through an collection objects in Java, you have an `Iterator` class which can solve your problem. That class has a `remove()` method to remove a key pair value from `HashMap`.

Possible duplicate of [How to remove a key from HashMap while iterating over it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092642/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hashmap-while-iterating-over-it)  and
[iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

**EDIT:**

Try this code on Java 7 and earlier versions:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    put("test", "test123");
    put("test2", "test456");
  }
};

for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
  if(entry.getKey().equals("test")) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

In Java 8, you can try this:

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e-> <boolean expression> );
```

Comment: Upvoting because you cannot comment, but this should be a comment if you had enough rep. If you included a full answer instead of just links to other questions, it would make a better answer

Comment: The Java 8 addition is great because this is one of the recent good changes on the `Map` API people need to know about. It was worth telling you to improve your answer, and upvoting you :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `Iterator` to remove from a collection while iterating over it.

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> i = H.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e = i.next();
    int v = e.getValue();
    if (v == 1)
        i.remove();
    else
        e.setValue(v - 1);
}
```

From the Documentation for `HashMap.EntrySet()` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa.

Comment: Think it's useful to quote the doc to prove the changes will be reflected to the map. This is not so trivial at first

Comment: @Dici I'll try to find relevant bits now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change something while you're iterating through it. When you change the `HashMap`, you change it's `keySet` too, and since you're iterating through that, Java throws an error. What you might have to do is add every key that needs to be removed to a separate list, then iterate through that list afterward.

Like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> otherList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int e : H.keySet()){
    h.put(e, H.get(e) - 1);
    if(H.get(e) == 0)
        otherList.add(e);
}

for(int e : otherList){
    H.remove(e);
}
```

Comment: According to the doc, it is possible to remove items from the set using `Iterator.remove`, and the changes will be reflected to the map. I don't think this is thread-safe though

Comment: no less thread safe than modifying maps from multiple threads anyway.