# Remove values from a list from another list

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

```
private Set<Entry<Personne, List<Precision>>> mapCorrelationEtat;

    for (Map.Entry<Personne, List<Precision>> entry : this.mapCorrelationEtat) {
        Personne key = entry.getKey();
        System.out.println(key.getIdPersonne());
    }
```

in this `linkedhashmap` I have some values, I want to remove some values from an another `List`

```
keyList: [1,2,5];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it a list of `keys` or `values`?

Comment: @Daniel a list of `keys`

Comment: Do you want to remove entire Entry (key,value pair) or only value for Entry for selected key (you could set that value to some neutral data or null)?

Comment: @Pshemo want to remove entire Entry (key,value pair)

Comment: Your question looks like duplicate of [How to remove a key from HashMap while iterating over it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092642/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hashmap-while-iterating-over-it). Is there any reason I shouldn't vote it as duplicate?

Comment: "i want to remove some values from an another List" is confusing. It may suggest that you want to edit list and remove some values from it. It can also be understood as you want to remove from map some elements which also exist in list. To get rid of this confusion try to add to your question simple example of input and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-) on [`keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--):

```
map.keySet().removeAll(keyList);
```

Comment: It looks like keys in map are instances of `Personne` class, but list contains only persons ID.

Comment: @Pshemo That seems correct from the code. Yet it is not what the OP describes :-/

Comment: @Pshemo overriden `Personne::toString()`??

Comment: @Mercer What is your Map then? Maps which implement `java.util.Map`  interface like `LinkedHashMap` must have this method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--

Comment: @JeanLogeart I suspect that OP is looking for something more like `map.keySet().removeIf(person -> listOfIDToRemove.contains(person.getIdPersonne()));`