# Can I use keySet to modify HashMap during iteration?

Tags: java, collections, iteration

I know that collections shouldn't be modified during iteration. So we should have workaround.

I have a code:

```
Map<Key, Value> map = getMap(); // map generating is hidden
for (Key key : map.keySet()) {
  if (isToRemove(key)) {
    map.remove(key);
  } else {
    map.put(key, getNewValue());
  }
}
```

Is it undefined behavior or valid code?

keySet documentation sais that changes of the map are reflected in returned set and vice-versa. Does it mean that previous code is unacceptable?

Comment: What you are asking seems unclear to me. You are generating a map, and want to remove keys after? why not prevent adding keys rather than adding them and remove them?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What's the purpose of your question, quiz us?

Comment: I would prefer to put all keys that should be removed in a set and after the loop I would loop through the set and remove the keys from the map.

Comment: You have the answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092642/how-to-remove-a-key-from-hashmap-while-iterating-over-it

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The code works. But I'm not sure that it works always correctly. I know there are situations when error appears only in specific situations. That's my question about. Am I clear now?

Comment: @Nimtar `Map` doesn't have `add()` method. I suppose that you would write `put()`.

Comment: @davidxxx, yes, my fault. I couldn't use "copy and paste", so had the mistake.  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [HashMap.keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet--) method states more precisely:

> The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in
>   the set, and vice-versa.

It means that the elements returned by `keySet()` and the keys of the `Map` refer to the same objects. So of course changing the state of any element of the `Set` (such as `key.setFoo(new Foo());`) will be reflected in the Map keys and reversely.

You should be cautious and prevent the map from being modified during the `keyset()` iteration :

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of
>   the iteration are undefined

You can remove entries of the map as :

> The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding
>   mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll,
>   retainAll, and clear operations.

But you cannot add entries in :

> It does not support the add or addAll operations.

So in conclusion, during `keySet()` iterator use `Set.remove()` or more simply iterate with the `Iterator` of the `keySet` and invoke `Iterator.remove()` to remove elements from the map.
You can add new elements in a temporary Map that you will use after the iteration to populate the original Map.

For example :

```
Map<Key, Value> map = getMap(); // map generating is hidden

Map<Key, Value> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Iterator<Key> keyIterator = map.keySet().iterator(); keyIterator.hasNext();) {
    Key key = keyIterator.next();
    if (isToRemove(key)) {
        keyIterator.remove();
    }
    else {
        tempMap.put(key, getNewValue());
    }
}

map.putAll(tempMap);
```

**Edit :**
Note that as you want to modify existing entries of the map, you should use an `Map.EntrySet` as explained in the [Stuart Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712527/270371).
In other cases, using an intermediary `Map` or a `Stream` that creates a new Map is required.

Comment: You can only use `Iterator.remove()` if you're iterating. Otherwise you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 7):

The [answer from davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49688209/1441122) is correct (+1) in pointing out that the *view collections* on the Map are linked to the map, and that **modifications to the map while iterating a view collection may result in `ConcurrentModificationException`.** The view collections on a map are provided by the `entrySet`, `keySet`, and `values` methods.

Thus, the original code:

```code
    Map<Key, Value> map = getMap();
    for (Key key : map.keySet()) {
        if (isToRemove(key)) {
            map.remove(key);
        } else {
            map.add(key, getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

will most likely throw `ConcurrentModificationException` because it modifies the map during each iteration.

It's possible to remove entries from the map while iterating a view collection, if that view collection's iterator supports the `remove` operation. The iterators for HashMap's view collections do support this. It is **also** possible to set the value of a particular map entry (key-value pair) by using the `setValue` method of a `Map.Entry` instance obtained while iterating a map's `entrySet`. **Thus, it's possible to do what you want to do within a single iteration, without using a temporary map**. Here's the code to do that:

```java
    Map<Key, Value> map = getMap();
    for (var entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); entryIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        var entry = entryIterator.next();
        if (isToRemove(entry.getKey())) {
            entryIterator.remove();
        } else {
            entry.setValue(getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

Note the use of Java 10's `var` construct. If you're not on Java 10, you have to write out the type declarations explicitly:

```java
    Map<Key, Value> map = getMap();
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Key, Value>> entryIterator = map.entrySet().iterator(); entryIterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<Key, Value> entry = entryIterator.next();
        if (isToRemove(entry.getKey())) {
            entryIterator.remove();
        } else {
            entry.setValue(getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

Finally, given that this is a moderately complicated map operation, it might be fruitful to use a stream to do the work. Note that this creates a new map instead of modifying an existing map in-place.

```code
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    import static java.util.Map.entry; // requires Java 9

    Map<Key, Value> result =
        getMap().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> ! isToRemove(e.getKey()))
                .map(e -> entry(e.getKey(), getNewValue()))
                .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: `Entry.setValue()` was really the thing to use in this case as the actual code didn't add but modified a new element in the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code you get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Here is how you do it instead, using an iterator over the keys set or the equivalent Java8+ functional API:

```
Map<String, Object> bag = new LinkedHashMap<>();
bag.put("Foo", 1);
bag.put("Bar", "Hooray");

// Throws ConcurrentModificationException
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : bag.entrySet()) {
    if (e.getKey().equals("Foo")) {
        bag.remove(e.getKey());
    }
}

// Since Java 8
bag.keySet().removeIf(key -> key.equals("Foo"));

// Until Java 7
Iterator<String> it = bag.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().equals("Bar")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```