# Is it safe to delete HashMap's entry when iterating over its values?

Tags: java

Assuming I know the key, is it possible to remove it when iterating over

```
for (ExampleClass e : map.values()) {
    if (condition) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

I have found a related question ([iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)), but it assumes we are iterating over the key set. Does the same apply to the value set?

Comment: sometimes I wonder what would be quicker, testing to see what happens or asking at SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`HashMap` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

So you can't use `map.remove(key)`.

From the javadoc for [`HashMap#values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--):

> The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations.

So you can use `Iterator#remove()` to remove entries from the value set.