# ConcurrentModificationException with ViewTreeObserver onPreDrawListener

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` that gets created in my method

```
final HashMap<Long, Rect> listViewItemBounds = new HashMap<Long, Rect>();
```

that saves all the bounds of visible views in a ListView

```
for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View child = getChildAt(i);
    if(child != null){
        int position = firstVisiblePosition+i;
        long itemID = adapter.getItemId(position);
        Rect startRect = new Rect(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getRight(),child.getBottom());
        listViewItemBounds.put(itemID, startRect);
        listViewItemDrawables.put(itemID, getBitmapDrawableFromView(child));
    }

}
```

then I start an `OnPreDrawListener` on the ListView

```
final ViewTreeObserver observer = getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        .
        .  
        .
    }
)};
```

and in the onPreDrawListener I loop through he hashmap to get the bounds of the saved views

```
for (Long itemId: listViewItemBounds.keySet()) { //points here
    .
    .
    .
    istViewItemBounds.remove(itemId);
}
```

the problem comes when I change/update the adapter where all this gets called again and `onPreDraw` is currently looping through the hashmap while it is being updated again due to the adapter change.

So how can I prevent the concurrency here so I dont get `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Stacktrace:

```
08-31 19:09:41.398  29127-29127/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:792)
            at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:819)
            at com.tyczj.myapp.views.HeaderGridView$3.onPreDraw(HeaderGridView.java:511)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edit:

```
Iterator<Long> it = listViewItemBounds.keySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        long itemId = it.next(); //error
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never remove entries from a hashMap while iterating over its keySet unless you do it using an Iterator and use its remove() method. This is where the ConcurrentModificationException comes from. It's nothing to do with threads.

Comment: You are correct, i wasn't. Mea culpa for not seeing the remove() call.

Comment: No worries. My first attempt at answering the question wasn't exactly clear - I was trying to type code on a mobile with limited success.

Comment: ok see my edit, I changed to use `Iterator` but now I get the error on `it.next()` did I miss something?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to save it its there, yes same error

Comment: The usual way is to iterate over Map.Entry objects. See this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1884889/3973077