# Android Bundle Iterator to Put and Remove Entries

Tags: java, android, iterator, bundle

I am seeking a method to iterate over the entries contained in a [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) object. Currently, I am incorrectly using a For Each approach:

```
for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
    if ("videourl".equals(key.toLowerCase()) || "priority".equals(key.toLowerCase())) {
        // Save value to bundle using lowercase key value
        extras.putString(key.toLowerCase(), (String) extras.get(key));
        // Remove original version of this bundle entry
        extras.remove(key);
    }
}
```

The problem with the approach shown above is that it risks arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

I've seen Iterator implementations for Map objects (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1884916/3957979):

```
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
  Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
  if(entry.getKey().equals("test")) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

However, I don't have direct access to the Bundle's entries so I can't use the same approach.

Please let me know if Iterators can be used with Bundle objects or please suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a way to use an iterator to add and remove entries to the Bundle.  My workaround is to save entries I want to add into a temporary Bundle object and to save the original key names for the entries I want to delete to a List.  See the code below:

```
// Loop through all messages and change the extras' key names to lowercase (only for keys of interest)
Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();
ArrayList<String> keysToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
Bundle extras = messages.get(i).getExtras();

for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
    // Check if key is not all lower case and if it is a key of interest
    if (!key.equals(key.toLowerCase()) && isKeyOfInterest(key)) {
        // Save value to bundle using lowercase key value
        tempBundle.putString(key.toLowerCase(), extras.getString(key));
        // Add original version of this key to a list for later deletion
        keysToBeRemoved.add(key);
    }
}

// Remove original entries from message extras
for (String originalKey : keysToBeRemoved) {
    extras.remove(originalKey);
}

// Add all new bundle entries to message extras
extras.putAll(tempBundle);
```

Still, if anyone does figure out how to use an Iterator with a Bundle, I'd love to know!