# Removing an element from a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to remove an element from my *map* and it is giving an error.

**CODE:**

```
Map<String, String> map = ["a":"test",
           "b":"test",
           "c":"test",
           "d":""]

for (data in map.entrySet()){
    if (data.getValue() != ""){
        map.remove(data.getKey())
    }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Caught: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException*
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at first_script.run(first_script.groovy:6)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I know it´s happening because I am trying to remove it at the same time. is there any way of doing it without creating a list for the elements I need to remove ?

Comment: It's happening because you are removing something from the map while you are looping through it at the same time

Comment: Duplicate of [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `removeIf`, note also that you have to use `equals` to check strings :

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> !e.getValue().equals(""));
```

or better in your case, you can use `isEmpty` :

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty())
```

Or mach better and because you based on the values in your condition, you can use `values()`, instead of `entrySet()`:

```
map.values().removeIf(v -> !v.isEmpty());
```