# How to delete all record having frequency 1 in HashMap in one Pass?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I want to delete the key having frequency 1 but i got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationExceptionat java.base/java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1495)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1518)
at Temp3.main(Temp3.java:14)
```

How to solve it ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class Temp3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
         map.put(1,1);
         map.put(2,1);
         map.put(3,1);
         map.put(4,2);

         for(int k: map.keySet()){
             if( map.get(k) == 1){
                 map.remove(k);
             }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: While you are iterating over the map, you cannot modify it or else you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Use an `Iterator` that supports remove, or temporarily copy your elements to remove to a new data structure and remove them afterwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Collection.removeIf()` and the `Map.values()` method:

```
map.values().removeIf(i -> i.equals(1));
```

Which removes all elements from the map which are equal to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the map while you are iterating it.
Possible solutions:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class Temp3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
         map.put(1,1);
         map.put(2,1);
         map.put(3,1);
         map.put(4,2);
         Integer key = null;
         for(int k: map.keySet()){
             if( map.get(k) == 1){
                 key == k;
                 break;
             }
          }
         map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Or just

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class Temp3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
         map.put(1,1);
         map.put(2,1);
         map.put(3,1);
         map.put(4,2);

         map.remove((Integer)1);
    }
}
```

Comment: map.Remove((Integer)1) gives error saying that " Can't find symbol "

Comment: I'm sorry, I used the capital letter for "Remove". I'm editing the answer

Comment: i want to remove all the keys having frequency 1 , your solution will remove only one record

Comment: what do you mean? you can have only one record with a given key