# A way to remove an entry in maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I was told that I should remove the last or third entry of the mapping, but I can't find any solution to these on how to get the specific entry and remove it.

Here is the code:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    String input1, input2;
    Map<String, String> students = new HashMap<>();
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            System.out.print("Enter student number " + i + ": ");
            input1 = reader.next();
            
            System.out.print("Enter first name " + i + ": ");
            input2 = reader.next();
            
            students.put(input1, input2);
        }
        
        System.out.println("Student List:");
        
        for(Map.Entry entry: students.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

I tried using the `students.remove(students.get(3), students.get(3));` but still it doesn't work. Is there a possible solution to this? Please help.

Comment: HashMaps don't have order -- what does "last or third entry" mean?

Comment: Use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap

Comment: You could use a `LinkedHashMap`, this preserves the insertion order. A regular `HashMap` doesn't. A better solution would likely be not to use a map at all. Instead create `Student` objects and store in a `List`, then use `list.remove(2)` to remove the third element.

Comment: @nanofarad, what I mean is the last user input. As u can I see I am asking for the user to enter which student id becomes the key and the value goes for the first name of the student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your case it might be well enough to remove the last entry directly instead of looping through the map trying to find it. Use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve order when printing out the entries:

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        
String input1, input2;
LinkedHashMap<String, String> students = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        
String last = null;
        
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter student number " + i + ": ");
    input1 = reader.next();
            
    System.out.print("Enter first name " + i + ": ");
    input2 = reader.next();
            
    students.put(input1, input2);
            
    if (i == 3) {
        last = input1;
    }
}
        
students.remove(last);
        
System.out.println("Student List:");
        
for (Map.Entry entry: students.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to replace it with the one I should input after the removing? It's something like this "After remove the last entry, you must enter another input and replace the one you remove with the new entry.

Comment: Yes. Just add it. It will appear at the end of the map automatically.

Comment: Oh, now I get it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please use LinkedHashMap.It extends HashMap and maintains a linked list of the entries in the map, in the order in which they were inserted.

```
Map<String, String> students = new LinkedHashMap <>();
```

Comment: Does it still has `remove();` If I'd use that how could I remove the last entry from the user inputs? Thanks anyways

Comment: Yes you get the last entry from the Map and delete it viva remove()

Answer (score 0):

From [iterating over and removing from a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884889/iterating-over-and-removing-from-a-map) example:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {
  {
    put("test", "test123");
    put("test2", "test456");
  }
};

for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
    if(entry.getKey().equals("test")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

You can do something like

```
int size = map.entrySet();
int i = 0;
for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {

    Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
    if(i == size - 1) { // last
//     if(i == 2) { // 3rd
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

However note that the above operation can be `O(n)` for hashmap. `LinkedHashMap` as other have pointed out can have a `O(1)` per deletion time

Comment: Oh, so after getting the inputs I have to get the size and iterate it?